# How do I dynamically populate the options in a combobox inside of a grid based on another row in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, datagrid, combobox, mxml

I'm trying to setup a DataGrid that contains a column of combo boxes.  The values of the combo boxes are defined by data specific to that row.  I cannot get this to work though, I'm asking for a solution to this, either fixing what I have below or a recommendation on a different way.

One of the columns of my DataGrid has an object derived from a ComboBox for an ItemEditor. The itemEditor is set like this:

```
    <mx:DataGridColumn editorDataField="selectedItem" dataField="type" editable="true" >
        <mx:itemEditor>
            <mx:Component>
            <FilterCell:SelectCellBase initialize="set_combo()" grid="{this}"/>
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemEditor>
    </mx:DataGridColumn>
```

So that when the itemEditor is generated (when the user double clicks on the cell) the data is populated.

Then, the SelectCellBase set_combo() function is defined as such:

```
            public function set_combo( ) : void 
            {
                var type : String = grid.dataProvider[grid.selectedIndex]['type'];

                if( 'text' == type )
                {
                    this.dataProvider = text;
                }
                else
                {
                    this.dataProvider = number;
                }
            }
```

This implementation isn't working though because when I try to call grid.selectedIndex this always seems to return -1.

What am I doing wrong, or what better way is there to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you're inside of an `<mx:Component>` the scope is local, and no longer set to the outside MXML file.  So when you have:

```
<mx:Component>
<FilterCell:SelectCellBase initialize="set_combo()" grid="{this}"/>
</mx:Component>
```

the "this" you're referring to is the inline component you've defined, not the base MXML component you're working on.  The easy fix is to change it to

```
<mx:Component>
<FilterCell:SelectCellBase initialize="set_combo()" grid="{outerDocument}"/>
</mx:Component>
```

the outerDocument variable is automatically set when you're inside of an `<mx:Component>` tag, and can be used to access anything needed from the parent scope.